Should I use an ordinal regression?
I have intention to return to teaching on a likert scale 1-5 as my outcome variable and wellbeing and job satisfaction as continuous predictor variables. I have also data regarding age, sex, years out of teaching and current job.
The data is positively skewed for the outcome variable at the moment (with most participants answering '1'). I am considering merging 1 and 2 into 'unlikely' categories, maintaining 3 as 'neutral' and merging 4 and 5 as 'likely' to make the groups more equal for an ordinal regression. Originally I was hoping to run a multiple regression but made a mistake with choosing a non-continuous outcome variable. What should I do now to make the chances of a good model fit more likely?

Sorry, maybe I am missing something. Why do you need to merge the ordinal categories?

Merging the categories sounds like an XY problem. What is the question that you're actually trying to answer?

Ordinal regression is a great choice.  There are lots of resources about ordinal regression here: https://www.fharrell.com/post/rpo/
Alternatively, you could arguably do linear regression:

Norman, Geoff. "Likert scales, levels of measurement and the “laws” of statistics." Advances in health sciences education 15 (2010): 625-632.

To be safe, you could use bootstrap confidence intervals and pvalues or robust sandwich standard errors, both of which do not assume normally distributed residuals.
Here is R code for all 3 approaches:
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rms));
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(boot.pval));
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lmtest));

### Ordinal regression
d <- datadist(mtcars);
options(datadist = 'd');
fit.ord <- orm(mpg ~ hp + disp, data = mtcars);
print(fit.ord)
#> Logistic (Proportional Odds) Ordinal Regression Model
#> 
#> orm(formula = mpg ~ hp + disp, data = mtcars)
#> 
#>                        Model Likelihood               Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
#>                              Ratio Test                      Indexes          Indexes    
#> Obs            32    LR chi2      55.45    R2                  0.825    rho     0.939    
#> Distinct Y     25    d.f.             2    R2(2,32)            0.812                     
#> Median Y     19.2    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    R2(2,31.9)          0.812                     
#> max |deriv| 0.003    Score chi2   49.08    |Pr(Y>=median)-0.5| 0.433                     
#>                      Pr(> chi2) <0.0001                                                  
#> 
#>      Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
#> hp   -0.0202 0.0085 -2.38  0.0175  
#> disp -0.0253 0.0064 -3.96  <0.0001

### Linear regression
fit.lm <- lm(mpg ~ hp + disp, data = mtcars);

# Bootstrap inference
set.seed(123);
boot.pval::boot_summary(fit.lm);
#> Loading required namespace: boot
#>                Estimate Lower.bound  Upper.bound p.value
#> (Intercept) 30.73590425 28.27397139 33.384273431   0.000
#> hp          -0.02484008 -0.04892851  0.003940325   0.089
#> disp        -0.03034628 -0.04523647 -0.016095086   0.001

# data.frame of results using robust standard errors
res <- as.data.frame(lmtest::coeftest(fit.lm, vcov = sandwich::vcovHC(fit.lm, type = "HC3"))[,], check.names = FALSE); 
res
#>                Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 30.73590425 1.593150356 19.292532 4.347247e-18
#> hp          -0.02484008 0.013203642 -1.881305 7.000434e-02
#> disp        -0.03034628 0.007949408 -3.817426 6.552602e-04

Created on 2024-11-13 with reprex v2.0.2
